# Error por tiempo de espera al llamar a una api en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

tengo una aplicación en windforms, que llama a una api en .net, pero da el siguiente error:
**The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.**

Esto se debe porque en el lado del cliente, que hago la petición, tiene tiempo limite. Ya que en la api, se demora bastante por un proceso que hace de comunicación.

Este es el codigo desde el cliente, que llama a la api.

```
  public string llamar_api_khipu(string tipobanco,
        string host,
        string user,
        string dataBase,
        string puerto,
        string passworddb,
        string codigobanco,
        string UserName,
        string Password,
        string EnterpriseIdentity,
        string Role,
        string Agreement,
        string accountNumber,
        string BookingDateStart,
        string BookingDateEnd)
    {

        string respuesta = "";
        Respuesta obj_result = Task.Run(() => respuestaJson(tipobanco,
         host,
         user,
         dataBase,
         puerto,
         passworddb,
         codigobanco,
         UserName,
         Password,
         EnterpriseIdentity,
         Role,
         Agreement,
         accountNumber,
         BookingDateStart,
         BookingDateEnd)).Result;

        respuesta = obj_result.datos;
        return respuesta;
    }


    public async Task<Respuesta> respuestaJson(string tipobanco,
        string host,
        string user,
        string dataBase,
        string puerto,
        string passworddb,
        string codigobanco,
        string UserName,
        string Password,
        string EnterpriseIdentity,
        string Role,
        string Agreement,
        string accountNumber,
        string BookingDateStart,
        string BookingDateEnd)
    {
        string urlApi = $"http://localhost:17649/obtienerespuestakhipu?tipobanco={tipobanco}&host={host}" +
            $"&user={user}&dataBase={dataBase}&puerto={puerto}&passworddb={passworddb}&codigobanco={codigobanco}" +
            $"&UserName={UserName}&Password={Password}&EnterpriseIdentity={EnterpriseIdentity}&Role={Role}" +
            $"&Agreement={Agreement}&accountNumber={accountNumber}&BookingDateStart={BookingDateStart}&BookingDateEnd={BookingDateEnd}";
        Respuesta resp = new Respuesta();


        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 80;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                HttpResponseMessage respuesta = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlApi);

                if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Leer y deserializar el contenido JSON
                    string contenidoJson = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var datosDeserializados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respuesta>(contenidoJson);

                    resp.datos = datosDeserializados.datos;
                    // Trabajar con los datos deserializados

                    // Puedes adaptar esto según la estructura de tus datos JSON
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error en la llamada a la API. Código de estado: {respuesta.StatusCode}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

    
            return resp;
    }
```

Quería saber como haga para darle mas tiempo desde el cliente. Intente usar DefaultConnectionLimit , pero aun así, me da el error. Desde ya, gracias.Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de darle al `HttpClient` el tiempo de espera que consideres.

```
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-8.0